# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer_Unable to fix using previous answers

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this is a duplicate question but I tried all the previous answers. Not working for me. So I give here my code. When try to load more than 2000 record I got this error.

> "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property."

In Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchFilter sf)
{
Model m = new Model();
IList<Info> Details;
IList<rViewModel> RLst = new List<rViewModel>();
using (var db = new con())
 {
RLst = (from p in Details
      select new rViewModel
      {
      Id=p.Id,
      Description = p.Description,
      Remark = p.Remark,                               
   }).ToList();
   m.Result = RLst;
}
return View(m);
}
```

In View,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Product').dataTable({
                "columnDefs": [
                     { "width": "20%", "targets": 0, "orderable": true, },
                     { "width": "40%", "targets": 1,"orderable": true, },
                     { "width": "40%", "targets": 2,"orderable": true, },                     
                ],"oLanguage": {"sSearch": "Filter:"}
            });
            var t = $('#Product').DataTable();
            t.clear();t.draw();

            var model =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Result));
            if(model!=null && model.length>0 )
            {
                AddData(model);
            }
            $('#Id').focus();
        });
```

Result Model is actually a partial view.
On the line in view,

```
var model =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Result));
```

I got this error. Error image attached below[image: Error image attached here]

How to fix?

I tried adding

```
<system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
```

in web.config already its not working.stuck in this for more than 2 days.. Kindly help..

Comment: Refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/7207539#7207539

Comment: Why would anybody be serializing or deserializing 2000 records? Even if you fix the issue that you have, the performance will be bad. You probably need to re-think your design.

Comment: This issue seems similar, what you need is setting up `JavaScriptSerializer` with customized `MaxJsonLength`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155468/json-encode-throwing-exception-json-length-exceeded (check out the reason in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/7207539#7207539 as well).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json Encode throwing exception json length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155468/json-encode-throwing-exception-json-length-exceeded)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you mr.Tetsuya Yamamoto for your reference. So far I tried all the link. But as per your link I tried the coding below.

In view

```
@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    var jsonModel = serializer.Serialize(Model.Result);
}
```

and at the line where I got error,I changed my one

```
var model =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Result));
```

into the line as below:

```
var model =@Html.Raw(jsonModel);
```

Previously also I tried these coding, but wrongly entered in controller. From your link only I find out need to put in view. This will help some one whose web.config declaration is not working.

Link Courtesy(once again) as follows:  [Json Encode throwing exception json length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155468/json-encode-throwing-exception-json-length-exceeded)

Answer (score 1):

"jsonSerialization maxJsonLength" did not work for me on this problem

But I reference @Halim answer.

This also works for me:

previous code with the problem:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        modelname(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    });
</script>
```

code resolution:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        var jsonModel = serializer.Serialize(Model);
        modelname(jsonModel)
    });
</script>
```