# While converting ViewBag.JsonData from View in JavaScript, getting The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jsonserializer

I'm working on a project where I've to pass a huge list of data (500 000 records or more) through ViewBag. From my controller, I'm sending data shown as below.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var list = new List<DropdownList>();
    
  for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
  {
     list.Add(new DropdownList() { id = i, text = "Test Data-" + i });
  }
  ViewBag.JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
  return View();
}
```

And from my view, I'm using the following code to parse that data in JavaScript. While trying this code getting the maxJsonLength exceeds the error.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.JsonData));
});
</script>
```

I also tried this & It's working with 500k records while data does not contain special characters. If data contain some special character then it's not working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   JSON.parse('@ViewBag.JsonData');
});
</script>
```

*Note:* I'm not getting error in *.cs* (c# code) file cause [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config) solution already implemented in my project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MaxJsonLength exception in ASP.NET MVC during JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer)

Comment: Oleg Naumov, No it’s not. It worked when error generating in c# code. But I'm getting error while Working viewbag data in cshtml file.

Comment: `500_000` items in a drop-down list seems like a *terrible* user experience. If the user can read and discard one item every second, it would take them nearly six days to work their way through the list. There must be a better option - for example, let the user start typing what they're looking for, and then load matching data on demand. Eg: [Select2's AJAX data source](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax).

Comment: Richard you are right.  And I'm doing this for select2. And I've a purpose to do that though it’s it’s not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error of MaxJsonLength overflow issues, This isn't a JavaScript issue but issues on C#. It doesn't support a large number of data sets in `Json.Encode`.

It's possible to tackle this situation only this way of a `JavascriptSerializer` and setting the `MaxJsonLength` property manually or only used by **`Newtonsoft.Json`**

**C# Codes**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = new List<DropdownList>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new DropdownList() { id = i, text = "Test Data-" + i });
        }            
        
        //First solutions with JavaScriptSerializer
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
        ViewBag.DataAsList = serializer.Serialize(list);

        //Second Solutions with Newtonsoft.Json
        ViewBag.DataAsList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Razor Pages**

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function mockDataForDataAsList() {
                return @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataAsList);
            }  
            console.log(mockDataForDataAsList());
        });
  </script>
```

**Console Log**
[image]

In this scenario, you can handle ***2 million records*** within a few seconds. Hope you got your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You *are* getting the error in "C# code". This is not a JavaScript issue.

If editing `web.config` doesn't help, you can try using an instance of a `JavascriptSerializer` and setting the `MaxJsonLength` property manually:

```
@{
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
    
   var jsonData = serializer.Serialize(@ViewBag.JsonData);
}
```

See more [here](https://rion.io/2013/04/28/handling-larger-json-string-values-in-net-and-avoiding-exceptions/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155468/json-encode-throwing-exception-json-length-exceeded/39277843).